# Resolving facelets components at runtime

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

do you know a way to select a different facelets component at runtime?

I've got some of code similar to this:

```
<s:fragment rendered="#{r== 'case1'}">
     <div>
           <ui:include src="case1.xhtml" />
     </div>
 </s:fragment>
 <s:fragment rendered="#{r== 'case2'}">
     <div>
            <ui:include src="case2.xhtml" />
     </div>
 </s:fragment>
```

I'd like to write

```
<ui:include src="#{r}.xhtml" />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution should work OK - the [src attribute](https://facelets.dev.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#template-include) can be a literal or an EL expression. You might want to make the expression use a managed bean property or resolve it through a [function](https://facelets.dev.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html#taglib-create-function). That way, you can ensure that it is never null (you could return a reference to an empty page if it was). You'll probably get a 404 error if #{r} resolves to null.

```
<ui:include src="#{myfn:resolveNotNull(r, 'pageIfRIsNull')}.xhtml" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure. An alternative though would be to use a template with a ui:insert and then direct to case1 or case2 which use ui:define programatically.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have selective use of ui:include with other JSF components.  Example:

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{!menuMBean.passwordResetRequired}">
    <ui:include src="homeNormal.xhtml" />
</h:panelGroup>
```